# How to display information relative to image clicked using pokemon API?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get and display the image and information of a clicked pokemon from pokemon API

HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="pokedex2.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="pokedex2.css">
<title>Pokedex v 2.0</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="all">
        <div id="pokemon">

        </div>
        <div id="chosen">

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     for(i = 1; i <=151; i ++){  
        $("#pokemon").append("<img id=pokepic" + i + " 
src='http://pokeapi.co/media/img/" + i +
    ".png'>");   
 }    
    var clicked = false;
    $("img").click(function(){
        clicked = true;
        console.log(this);

    if(clicked){
        $.get("http://pokeapi.co/api/v1/pokemon/" + i +"/", function(data){
            var str = "";
            str += "<h4>Types</h4>";
            str += "<ul>";
            var str2 = "";
            str2 += "<h4>height</h4>";
            str2 += "<ul>";
            var str3 = "";
            str3 += "<h4>weight</h4>";
            str3 += "<ul>";      
            for(i = 0; i < data.types.length; i ++){
                str += "<li>" + data.types[i].name + "</li>";           
            }
                str2 += "<li>" + data.height + "</li>";
                str3 += "<li>" + data.weight + "</li>";
                str += "</ul>"
                str2 += "</ul>"
                str3 += "</ul>"
                $("#chosen").html(str + str2 + str3);    }, "json");
                }

    else{
         clicked = false;
        }     
    })
});
```

At the moment, the only information being brought up are for the first 3 pokemon in the list, not for the pokemon that was clicked. I need to find the information associated with the clicked pokemon, like a pokedex.

I included console.log to show that whichever image is clicked, the picture, and pokepic ID number associated with that image appear in the console. Instead what I need is for the image and stats associated with each image to appear in the div labeled chosen

Comment: I'd recommend you to check eventListeners. Now you're trying to check with jquery's click() function, but withdocument.ready it will work for the loaded pictures before jquery started. With event listeners you can control all the DOM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your click event uses the i variable defined in your for loop. Since the function inside the click is always called after the loop is done, i is always 152. You need to read the current pokemon from your click event:

```
$('img').on('click', function(e){
    var pokemonId = e.target.id.split('pokepic')[1];
    $.get("http://pokeapi.co/api/v1/pokemon/" + pokemonId +"/", function(data){
        ...
    });
});
```